# Why do my MSI images look corrupted when using WiX?

Tags: image, wix, windows-installer

I'm setting a custom banner and dialog image for my [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) generated MSI.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="./build/msi/InstallerBanner.jpg" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="./build/msi/InstallerDialog.jpg" />
```

For some reason, the image becomes corrupted when built into the MSI. I've added the two images to my question for easy comparison. I've tried BMP and JPEG with a whole range of compression types - and they all look exactly the same. I can verify that I'm using exactly the correct image dimensions (500 by 63 pixels).

Here's the original image:
[Original image http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7016/installerbanner.jpg](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7016/installerbanner.jpg)

And here's what it looks like in the MSI:
[Image in use - 1 http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2996/bannerinuse.jpg](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2996/bannerinuse.jpg)

### Update:

Thanks for your answers, I got the *wrong* dimensions from [a tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson2.php), that's actually very out dated and (apparently) very inaccurate. Never the less, it's a good hacking resource. I'll stick to the manual in future!

Comment: not answer, but... tried png?  Its what I use and I've never had an issue.

Comment: WiX does not support PNG (only BMP and JPEG).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your image is too big dimension-wise. Banner Images must be 493 × 58 and your image is 500 × 63, causing it to be resized.

See [Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm)

By the way: nice to see Synergy2 is finally getting an update!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've been hammering the project with activity for a couple of months now and I think things are starting to progress. I hope you get chance to try it out. Shameless plug alert! http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/ - you may want to take a look at the issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Andrew's right. It's covered in wix.chm.

Those are the wrong dimensions. From the [relevant wix documentation topic](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm):

> **Replacing the default bitmaps**
>
> The WixUI dialog library includes
>   default bitmaps for the background of
>   the welcome and completion dialogs and
>   the top banner of the other dialogs.
>   You can replace those bitmaps with
>   your own for product branding
>   purposes. To replace default bitmaps,
>   specify WiX variable values with the
>   file names of your bitmaps, just like
>   when replacing the default license
>   text.
>
> Variable name / Description / Dimensions:
>
> - WixUIBannerBmp / Top banner / 493 × 58
> - WixUIDialogBmp / Background bitmap used on the welcome and completion dialogs / 493 × 312
> - WixUIExclamationIco / Exclamation icon on the WaitForCostingDlg / 32 × 32
> - WixUIInfoIco / Information icon on the cancel and error dialogs / 32 × 32
> - WixUINewIco / Button glyph on the / BrowseDlg 16 × 16
> - WixUIUpIco / Button glyph on the BrowseDlg / 16 × 16

Answer (score 1):

I found that to customize the WixUIDialogBmp for WiX 3.5, the dimensions **must** be 493x312 pixels. So, to make the banner only appear in the left 164 pixels of the dialog box, fill the right 329 pixels with white pixels.  Then it should display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using WiX ver. 3.7.1224.0 (Dec'12), I have to create an image 616 × 390 to fill the dialog and avoid stretching. The clear zone to the left of the dialog text is 234 pixels wide.

The banner is still 493 × 58.

Comment: I think this could be due to the scaling setting on your display.  616 = 493 * 1.25, 390 = 312 * 1.25.  Do we have to provide different images for different scales?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .bmp images with specified dimensions as shown below
[image]

For more info : https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html